# How to allow files with exec permission in NSOpenPanel?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, permissions, nsopenpanel

The Cocoa NSOpenPanel, in a third party open source library [VSTGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vstgui/), disables files that have exec permission set. The exec bit is not needed, but it often seems to be set on files created on Windows and downloaded to OS X.

The library uses `beginSheetForDirectory:file:types:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:` to display the panel. The given `types` parameter is a singleton array with a simple extension based UTI. What could possibly cause the panel to disallow these files and how and where can the behaviour be configured?

I'm aware that the method is or will be deprecated but right now i seem to be stuck on this. I'm on OS X 10.8 and the deployment target in Xcode is 10.5.

Edit:

The UTI used here is created with the function

```
CFStringRef UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(CFStringRef   inTagClass,
                                                  CFStringRef   inTag,
                                                  CFStringRef   inConformingToUTI)
```

with `kUTTagClassFilenameExtension` as `inTagClass`, the desired extension as `inTag` and `kUTTypeData` as `inConformingToUTI`. If i give the `types` parameter as an array with simple extension string, instead of a UTI, everything works as expected. So i guess the `kUTTypeData` hint kind of rules out files with exec bit set. Unfortunately the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Type_Tag_Classes) doesn't tell any other value for `inConformingToUTI` that would work.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the open panel has a delegate set, which implements the method

```
- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url
```

or similar. See the [NSOpenSavePanelDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) .

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not the case.